# how to require data attribute asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-data-attribute, required

How to require data attribute asp.net mvc?
There is an attribute

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^[a-яА-Яa-zA-Z .]+$", ErrorMessage = "Not name")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
```

works good:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Not name" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-яА-Яa-zA-Z .]+$" data-val-required="Name null" id="exampleInputName" name="Name" value="" type="text">
```

How to do it:

```
[Required ("if Html data Attribute data-adress-id!=empty")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-яА-Яa-zA-Z .]+$", ErrorMessage = "Not name")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
```

and:

```
 <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Not name" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-яА-Яa-zA-Z .]+$" data-val-required="Name null" id="exampleInputName" name="Name" data-adress-id="(IF THIS NOT NULL)" value="" type="text">
```

Attribute data-adress-id change JS Plugin. Thanks!

Javascript:

```
$("#exampleInputName").on("input", function (e) {
            if (isValidAdressPattern($(this).val())) {
            $(this).data('data-adress-id',adressGetId($(this).val()));
            "GOOD AND SUBMIT AND VALIDATE UNHIGHLIGH"
            } else {
            $(this).data('data-adress-id',null);
            "NOT GOOD AND NOT SUBMIT AND VALIDATE HIGHLIGH" 
            }

        });
```

Validator settings:

```
    $(function () {
        var valSettings = $("#formAddAdress").data("validator").settings
        var highlightBase = valSettings.highlight;
        var unhighlightBase = valSettings.unhighlight;

        valSettings.highlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            highlightBase(element, errorClass, validClass)
            $(element).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.form-line').addClass("error-line").removeClass("success-line");
        }
        valSettings.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            unhighlightBase(element, errorClass, validClass) 
            $(element).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.form-line').addClass("success-line").removeClass("error-line");
        }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"Attribute data-adress-id change JS Plugin"_?

Comment: This attribute changes in the JS code, where the correctness of the entered address is checked. If the address is correct, then the attribute has an address identifier (data-adress-id = "idadress = 11233212331223") else (data-adress-id = "null").

Comment: Please rephrase that.

Comment: I added the JS code in this post.

Comment: And added validator settings in post.

Comment: You cannot do that with a `[Required]` attribute (and you would never get server side validatiion because the server has no knowledge of your html attributes in a POST method. Add another property in your view model and use a conditional `[RequiredIf]` attribute (e.g. [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof)) so that its required based on the value of the other property.